# Query regarding numpy append function in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am struggling in appending a numpy array to other one..

```
data_X = load_dataset()
print(data_X.shape) # (6794, 11)
result_array = np.empty((0, 110))

for i in range(0, 1000, 10):
    arr_1d = data_X[i:i+10].reshape(1, 110)
    np.append(result_array, arr_1d, axis=0)

print(result_array.shape)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.. There is no error but shape of `result_array` is `(0,110)`. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `list.append`, `numpy.append` does not work in-place but returns a new object. To make your loop work you'd have to reassign to `result_array`.

Please also note that `numpy.append` is rather inefficient and should not be used that way.

Recommended ways of achieving the equivalent of your loop include

- preallocating using `np.empty` and then using slice assignment
- appending to a list and using `np.concatenate` in the end

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked after re-assignment.
    result_array=np.append(result_array, arr_1d, axis=0)